# Parse this Json to NSmutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

i've this unique text plain

```
{"id":"AALI.NG","data":["AALI","NG",19312,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
{"id":"AALI.RG","data":["AALI","RG",19500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
{"id":"AALI.TN","data":["AALI","TN",19500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
{"id":"ABBA.NG","data":["ABBA","NG",60,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
{"id":"ABBA.RG","data":["ABBA","RG",85,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
{"id":"ABBA.TN","data":["ABBA","TN",85,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
{"id":"ABDA.NG","data":["ABDA","NG",3500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}
```

then i change it to :

```
 {"stockQuote":[{"id":"AALI.NG","data":["AALI","NG",19312,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,70,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"},
{"id":"AALI.RG","data":["AALI","RG",19500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,26,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"},
{"id":"AALI.TN","data":["AALI","TN",19500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"},
{"id":"ABBA.NG","data":["ABBA","NG",60,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"},
{"id":"ABBA.RG","data":["ABBA","RG",85,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"},
{"id":"ABBA.TN","data":["ABBA","TN",85,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"},
{"id":"ABDA.NG","data":["ABDA","NG",3500,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],"req":"SQ"}]}
```

basicly type  of data i get from server is text/plain  and i need to add **{"stockQuote":[**,  "," and also **}]}** to make it like json...

the question is, how to parse it to json an `NSMutableArray` then i draw it to `UITableView`, how to do it?? should i change it to `NSDictionary` first and  then insert it to `NSMutableArray`?

Comment: you fix your problem?

Comment: almost.. let me try the code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second JSON is just an NSDictionary with a single object that is an NSArray.  So just take your normal array that you have in the first JSON, and do this:

```
NSArray *jsonArray = [jsonDic objectForKey:@"stockQuote"];
```

where jsonDic is your json's parse object with NSJSONSerialization method.